# Maven project builds but dependencies seem to be unavailable in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a multi-level Maven project that builds fine on the command-line using `mvn clean install` and builds in IntelliJ IDEA (2019.3) by manually running the parent project's `clean` and `install` phase. The Problems view shows nothing wrong. When I open files that have certain external libraries, they show as being unable to be resolved:

[image: bad imports]

I'm usually able to browse external libraries' contents in the project browser. I've noticed that these external libraries IntelliJ can't find are listed but not browsable.

[image: external libraries]

Other people working on our project with the same code base and same IntelliJ version don't seem to have this problem. I've tried:

- "Reimport all Maven projects"
- File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart
- Completely deleting my `~/.m2/repository`
- Completely deleting my `$PROJECT_ROOT/.idea` directory and reimporting
- Recloning and reimporting the project from scratch

None of the above seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root case for this problem was not identified and is still under investigation, but what can help is [removing the IDE settings](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) and starting with the defaults.

Comment: I believe this would've worked but I went for the nuclear option and got rid of all caches, preferences, IDE settings, etc. This worked.