# Intellij absolutely will not recognize classes in maven dependency javax.xml.rpc

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a multi-module maven project imported into IntelliJ. It had numerous dependencies, all which are recognized in the editor except for references to all classes in javax.xml.rpc.

1. The dependency jaxrpc:1.0.0 shows up in the dependencies viewer on the right-hand side.
2. The dependency jaxrpc:1.0.0 shows up when I run mvn dependency:tree
3. The JAR in .m2/../.........../jaxrpc-1.0.0.jar contains the classes I am referencing. I verified this by running jar -tf jaxrpc-1.0.0.jar

I tried:

1. Reimport the maven project.
2. Running mvn clean -U
3. Adding the compile to the jaxrpc dependency in my module's pom.xml
4. Adding Java EE facet to my module.

This is frustrating because:

1. The artifact absolutely undeniably is there.
2. All other dependencies work.
3. This maven project worked flawlessly in eclipse. I never had any compilation issues or editor issues. Sadly the employer-endorsed custom eclipse build crashes alot and is slow so I'm forced to try their endorsed version of IntelliJ.

Comment: please show your pom file ...BTW: Does your project build on plain command line?

Comment: Sadly this is a corporate pom file so I can't share it. The maven build compiles, although there are some tests with errors.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60583136/104891 for the similar issue. Does it help if you start IntelliJ IDEA with all the defaults after removing IDE folders? In case the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).